# Function that are not smooth because $f(U) \not \subset V$

Tags: smooth-manifolds, smooth-functions

In the book of Lee (page 35 of second edition) on smooth manifolds, for a map $f : M \rightarrow N$ between manifolds to be smooth, we have to prove in particular that for each point p in $M$ there is a coordinate domain $U$ containing p and V containing $f(p)$ such that $f(U) \subset V$ . I think he says that we cannot always have this if f is not continuous and he gives the example :

$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 \text{ if } x < 0 \\
1 \text{ if } x \ge 0
\end{cases}
$

but even in $p=0$ it seems to me that if we take $U=(-2,2)$ and $V=(-2,2)$ everything is okay.
There is something I don't get here.

Comment: You forgot the condition that the representation of $f$ in those charts has to be smooth in the usual sense of calculus.

Comment: The definition on wikipedia says it has to hold for any neighborhood containing the point in the codomain. Do you have the definition in a formal language or is it just english?

Comment: Maybe since the inverse image of f of a set containing $1$ but not $0$ is $x\geq 0$ (which is closed?) one can say something ...? Not sure though...

Comment: @Emil Are you talking about  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Smooth_functions_between_manifolds) definition on wikipedia? It seems to be the same as the one in Lee.

Comment: @KelvinLois: according to Lee's book, the condition you mention is satisfied, and the problem is, as the OP says, prove the existence of the such neighbourhoods. But I can't see how in $0$ $f$ can be continuous. I mean, in $\mathbb R$, we only need one chart $(U,\varphi)=(\mathbb R,id)$, and it is clear that $f$ is not smooth (even continuous). I know that Lee has an account in this site. Maybe the OP can change the title to include some reference to Lee's book and hope he clicks on.

Comment: @Dog_69 How can $f$ has a smooth representation ?. I think the point is that if we throw this condition away (that $f(U) \subseteq V$) by define new definition of smoothness (as in Problem 2.1) then we can have the function $f$ smooth in this new definition, but $f$ is still not continous. Note that the new definition of smoothness in problem 2.1 is not requiring $U\cap f^{-1}(V)$ is to be open in $M$. This this why we can say that by choosing $U=(-1,1),Id$ and $V=(1/2,3/2),Id$, the representation of $f$ is the restriction $f :[0,\infty) \to (1/2,3/2)$ is smooth in Euclidean sense.

Comment: @KelvinLois I don't know, I can understand it neither. But after reading the problem my impression was that. Anyway, Mr. Lee has given us the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for this function $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ to be smooth by my definition (which, as you pointed out, is the same as the one given by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness#Smooth_functions_between_manifolds)), there must be charts $(U,\varphi)$ containing $0$ and $(V,\psi)$ containing $1$ that satisfy two conditions:

1. $f(U)\subseteq V$, and
2. $\psi\circ f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth on the domain where it is defined, namely $\varphi(U\cap f^{-1}(V))$.

If, as you suggested, you take $(U,\varphi) = (V,\psi) = ((-2,2),\text{id})$, then #1 is satisfied but #2 is not.

On the other hand, the point of the problem you're looking at is to show that you can find another pair of charts that satisfies #2 but not #1.

The moral is that you need to be able to find charts satisfying both conditions in order to claim that $f$ is smooth, and for this particular $f$, there are no such charts.

Comment: A response from Mr. Lee himself. So cool!